# Python reading JSON in dataframe

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas

I have an SQL database which has two columns. One has the timestamp, the other holds data in JSON format

**for example df:**

```
ts                           data
'2017-12-18 02:30:20.553'   {'name':'bob','age':10, 'location':{'town':'miami','state':'florida'}}
'2017-12-18 02:30:21.101'   {'name':'dan','age':15, 'location':{'town':'new york','state':'new york'}}         
'2017-12-18 02:30:21.202'   {'name':'jay','age':11, 'location':{'town':'tampa','state':'florida'}}
```

**If I do the following :**

```
df = df['data'][0]
print (df['name'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

**I get :**

```
'bob'
```

Is there a way I can get all of the data correspondings to a JSON key for the whole column?

**(i.e. for the df column 'data' get 'name')**

```
'bob'

'dan'

'jay'
```

Essentially I would like to be able to make a new df column called 'name'

Comment: Do you want this to be a part of the SQL select statement? Or could you do `for entry in df['data']: print(entry['name'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))`

Comment: I should have been more clear, I want the result to be a new df column called 'name'

Comment: To get all the values for the `name` column in a list: `[entry['name'].encode('ascii', 'ignore') for entry in df['data']]`, then you have to do something like `ALTER TABLE ADD column_name datatype` and then insert your values

Comment: you can use `df["data"]apply(function)`to execute function for every row and get your name for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_normalize` i.e

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df['data'])['name']

0    bob
1    dan
2    jay
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, lets use `apply` with lambda function to select value from dictionary by key:

```
df['data'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

Output:

```
0    bob
1    dan
2    jay
Name: data, dtype: object
```

Comment: `.apply(dict.get, args=('name', ))` would also work, I think.